# Clojure read-line turning it into usefull vector

Tags: clojure

## Question:How to I turn Read-Line into a usable vector to pass in to another function to do work.

```
(defn iAcceptUserInputAsAVector [a b c] ( )) ; I do work with the userInput as a vector

(defn input []
   (let [userKeyboardInput ( read-line)]
     (
       [userKeyboardInput]; doesnt work I tried (vector userKeyboardInput)
     )
   )
 )
```

### Update 1: My Progress so far thanks to noisesmith

```
(defn input []( let [userKeyBoardInput [(read-line)]]
                (println userKeyBoardInput)
                ))
```

### Update 2 My current solution and working... I imagine it can be done so much better

```
(defn split-by-whitespace [s]
    (clojure.string/split s #"\s+"))

(defn input []
  ( let [userKeyBoardInput [(split-by-whitespace(read-line))]]
    ;Then insanity below is because I have to convert to integers, list then a vector. Why? map returns list 
    ;which I dont need instead I need a vector []
    ;Also the initial entry is returned as [[]] which I need to convert to [] for map to be able to take
    ;it as parameter. There probably a better way. Show me... 

    (def x (into[](map #(Integer/parseInt %) (into [](flatten [userKeyBoardInput])))))
     (println x)
     (myLoopFunc x); basically it takes my vector and does something .. not important

 ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parenthesis are not a grouping construct in Clojure.

There are two major errors in your code:

`((read-line))` this gets a string via `read-line` and then attempts to execute it. This will fail, strings do not implement `IFn`.

`([userKeyboardInput])` if the code even got this far, this would fail as well, because you can't call a vector as a function without providing any arguments.

In clojure, wrapping something in parens usually means you want to execute it as a function. Adding extraneous parens will easily break things.

Comment: So how do I take a string a make it into a vector? Do I split then try again?

Comment: Thanks to your comments i tried something slightly different(defn input []( let [userKeyBoardInput [(read-line)]]
                (println userKeyBoardInput)
                )). If i assume the user will put spaces between his input then maybe I can get what I need.

Comment: if you want to split the string you can use `clojure.string/split`

Answer (score 1):

I will comment on how to improve your current solution (source code comments removed, linenumbers added):

```
01: (defn split-by-whitespace [s]
02:     (clojure.string/split s #"\s+"))
03:
04: (defn input []
05:   ( let [userKeyBoardInput [(split-by-whitespace(read-line))]]
06:     (def x (into[](map #(Integer/parseInt %) (into [](flatten [userKeyBoardInput])))))
07:      (println x)
08:      (myLoopFunc x)
09:
10:  ))
```

The function `split-by-whitespace` looks good. Note that it already returns a vector. (Suppose `read-line` returned `"6 34 12"`. Then `split-by-whitespace` will give you `["6" "34" "12"]`). So when you call it in line 5, you do not need the `[]` around your call, because you don't want a vector in a vector. Therefore, you no longer need `flatten`. You can just map over the vector you already have. Then a function that did the desired transformation for you would look like this:

```
(defn string->number-vector   ; name is verbose but meaning is clear :)
  [s]
  (into []
    (map #(Integer/parseInt %)
         (split-by-whitespace s))))
```

And you might call it with `(myLoopFunc (string->number-vector (read-line)))`.